# How to make independent horizontal scrolling on a div container?

Tags: html, css

I want to make it so that one div can scroll horizontally independently of the other div. Scrolling divs should have a minimum width (e.g. 500px) and not be aligned to the width of the content. The other div has a width of 100%. How can i do this?

```
<div>
  <div #parent style="width: 100%"></div>
  <div #child style="position: relative; width: 100%">
    <div #child class="child-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.child-container {
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: auto;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  min-width: 500px;
}
```

I edited the post to be more realistic

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have tagged CSS but did not provide any, can you please add your CSS or edit your tag.

Comment: @BeerusDev
I added CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the CSS property `overflow-x` which will allow you to specify the overflow behavior with CSS.

Here is MDN's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) on this property.

> The overflow-x CSS property sets what shows when content overflows a block-level element's left and right edges. This may be nothing, a scroll bar, or the overflow content.

---

## Update

Here is a working example of what you are asking for.  If I'm not understanding your question, please let me know.

```css
.padding {
  padding:25px;
}

.container {
  max-width:400px;
}

.child-container {
  background:#dedede;
  overflow-x:scroll
}

.child-item {
  min-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container padding" style="background:#ededed;">
  <div class="padding">
    <h1>Parent</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child-container padding">
    <div class="child-item">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know about this property. But it didn't help me. I'm scrolling through the whole page, not just the bottom div

Comment: @AntonGolubev I have just updated my answer to show a working example.  If this is not the behavior that you're looking for, can you please add more detail to your question? Thanks :)